# Can I use a Tensor as a list index?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

I have this Custom Keras Layer that chooses between elements of a list, like a Dense layer, and I want it to return the element of the list it predicted directly.
The list is a list of `Keras.layers.Layer`.
I have this piece of code:

```py
def call(self, inputs, context):   
    pred = tf.argmax(tf.matmul(context, self.kernel))
    return self.layers[pred](inputs)
```

It throws an error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Tensor`, which is understandable, but I can't find a way of making it work. The "pred" Tensor doesn't have a `.numpy` property, though I'm running the program eagerly, since this happens when the layer is being built.

I understand there may be no solutions, if so, submit ideas on how I could code this layer in another way.

Comment: I am not sure, but I don't think you can call `.numpy` when subclassing a `tf.keras.Layer`. I think everything in the call function must be declared in `tensorflow ` itself. So let's try that! How about grouping your `self.layers`  using `tf.concatenate`, `tf.stack` or `tf.layers.Concatenate` or something (instead of in a list), and select the correct ones by index using `tf.gather`?

Comment: @Frederik Bode You actually cannot call `.numpy` in a `tf.keras.layers.Layer`. Your idea sounds great, but once stacked (haven't tried the other options yet), the layer becomes a Tensor and you cannot call it as a function.

Comment: eurgh - it's super ugly but you could nest `tf.cond`: `tf.cond(tf.equals(pred, 0), self.layers[0](inputs), tf.cond(tf.equals(pred,1), self.layers[1](inputs), ...)`. You can probably format this little bit of graph construction using recursion or a for loop.

Comment: @ Frederik Bode I didn't even know tf.cond existed. Is this what you recommended ?

`for i, layer in enumerate(self.layers): tf.cond(tf.equals(pred, i), layer(inputs))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bigger problem.

This layer will not work, because you cannot get derivatives of `argmax`, the `kernel` will be impossible to train. And you will get an error message like "An operation has None for gradient"

As a workaround, I'd suggest you to:

- 1: calculate all layers (hope they have the same shape?)
- 2: stack their results in the second dimension: `tf.stack([listf_of_outputs],axis=1)`
- 2: take a `softmax` of the result of `matmul`
- 3: reshape the result of `softmax` to the same number of dimensions of the stacked result above: shape `(-1, number_of_layers, _other_dims_if_exist, 1)`
- 4: multiply (elementwise `*`) the stacked results by the reshaped softmax and sum the axis 1.

Comment: This explains why a prior layer of mine didn't work either. I'll try and code exactly that, and keep you posted on whether or not it has worked out or not. Thankfully, all the layers should have the same shape.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's the kind of mathematical trick I'm lacking currently.
I've been able to build my first Gated Model (even though I still need to improve the technique) !

Comment: :D -- If the results are not very ok, you can try `sigmoid` instead of `softmax`, in this case the gate will be very leaky or can also close all doors.

Comment: How would you parameter `sigmoid`, to have more or less "leaks" in the gate ? That could be a fairly interesting feature to my `GNNs`, which I want to be as customizable as possible.

Comment: I have no idea currently.... but the layer would just decide it by itself.

Comment: Final question, I hope, right now, with the softmax, how much are considered the layers that aren't predicted a lot (for example a layer that has .1 in the result of the `matmul`) ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The sum of all elements in softmax = 1

Comment: Does the prediction take other layers than the `argmax` ? I'm just a little confused, sorry for the lack of clarity

Comment: I've tried some simple tests, and, the layer performs worse than a `Dense` layer, even with a single `Dense` layer inside `self.layers`. I suspect your algorithms somehow interferes with the layer's prediction. If you want, I can send you a graph showing what I mean.

Comment: You must carefully keep track of the shapes. You must choose an axis to apply the softmax, and this axis must have the size = n_layers. (Any other axis will destroy the performance) -- You must also make sure that you stack the layers' outputs in this same axis!! And that both the stacked outputs and the softmax result have the same number of dimensions, meaning you might need to add ones to the dimensions just to complete them. ---- If you could share the exact shapes (including the batch size) of each layer output, and the shape of the matrix multiplication, I could probably help more.

Comment: Another thing you must be very careful about: `matmul` cannot be using the dimension 0 (batch size), so the shapes of the inputs to `matmul`  also matter.

Comment: I had made one mistake in coding what you said, that I finally found out. I confused the final `multiply` and used `matmul` instead, and it somehow worked, even though it destroyed all performances. Debugging was kind of hard, since you cannot directly access the shapes of the `SymbolicTensor`s. I then changed all the axis to match, on the `axis=1`. Now, my `Gate` Layers outperform `Dense` Layers for various tasks, with less parameters :)

Comment: Great :) -- Hint: `backend.int_shape` shows the shape of the symbolic tensors in Keras during compile time (may contain `None`).  And `backend.shape` gets the shape as a tensor, current true batch size, for use in runtime.

Comment: That's actually some nice tech here. I'm trying to find actual benchmarks to prove my layer's superiority to simply not using it. Since you almost entierely designed the maths behind it (at least the implementation of it), do you have any idea ? If every test goes as well as my first one, that could be a big deal, since you can literally slap it onto any model and make it slightly better.

Comment: This piece of code is part of a project about other NN architectures. The `Gate` layer has a pool of layers it can call, and will only call one of them on the input, depending on the context, thus having less weights for the same effect, and more adaptability (for RL for example). Tell me if you're interested

Comment: I am, but I'm not sure I understand how it has less weights when you have more layers.

Comment: How I'd do it is typically, instead of having `Dense(16)`, I'd have a Gate with two `Dense(8)`. Imagine the layer before was `Dense(16)` as well, you have `16*16+16=272` weights, against `16*8+8+C*2` where C would likely be small.
In a sense, it lets you cut your layers into different chuncks